# Removing element from JSON object depending on value

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON file which looks like so:

```
{
    "2018-1-15 22:35:22": {
        "entry": "1234",
        "ticket": "32432432432523",
        "name": "test"
    },

    "2018-1-15 23:35:22": {
        "entry": "5678",
        "ticket": "2485181851981",
        "name": "test2"
    }

}
```

And I have this code that checks if an entry value is in the JSON file:

```
const jsondata = require('./path/to/data.json');

function _isContains(json, value) {
    let contains = false;
    Object.keys(json).some(key => {
        contains = typeof json[key] === 'object' ? _isContains(json[key], value) : json[key] === value;
        return contains;
    });
    return contains;
}

var entryToDelete = 1234
if (_isContains(jsondata, entryToDelete) == true) {
    //delete the entire {} for the entryToDelete 
}
```

Basically I would like to delete the element if the entry already exists in the JSON file. So after the deletion of the element, JSON file should look like this:

```
{
    "2018-1-15 23:35:22": {
        "entry": "5678",
        "ticket": "2485181851981",
        "name": "test2"
    }   

}
```

I tried to use `delete jsondata[entryToDelete];`, but that did not delete the element.

Can someone please help me fix this.
Thanks,

Comment: If you return the string "2018-1-15 22:35:22" instead of a boolean, you can use `delete jsondata[key]`

Comment: You must find a way to call `delete jsondata['2018-1-15 23:35:22']` since that is the key for the object

Comment: @Anonymous - see my answer below

Comment: @some They are different, `2018-1-15 22:35:22` and `2018-1-15 23:35:22`

Comment: If you left a negative vote, please comment why. I don't understand what's wrong with this question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your script modified to work as desired:

```js
var jsonData = {
    "2018-1-15 22:35:22": {
        "entry": "1234",
        "ticket": "32432432432523",
        "name": "test"
    },

    "2018-1-15 23:35:22": {
        "entry": "5678",
        "ticket": "2485181851981",
        "name": "test2"
    }

}

function _isContains(json, value) {
    let contains = false;
    Object.keys(json).some(key => {
        contains = typeof json[key] === 'object' ? _isContains(json[key], value) : json[key] === value;
        return contains = key;
    });
    return contains;
}

var entryToDelete = 1234
var contains = _isContains(jsonData, entryToDelete)

if ( contains !== false) {
    delete jsonData[contains]
    console.log(jsonData)
}
```

Comment: @some can you explain what you mean by duplicate keys in this please?

Comment: `22` and `23`, they were different :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const jsondata = {
    "2018-1-15 22:35:22": {
        "entry": "1234",
        "ticket": "32432432432523",
        "name": "test"
    },

    "2018-1-15 23:35:22": {
        "entry": "5678",
        "ticket": "2485181851981",
        "name": "test2"
    }

}

function getKeyFromValue(json, value) {
    let output = null; // assume we don't find the entry
    Object.keys(json).some(key => {
      // if entry is equal to value, then set output to key
      if ( json[key].entry === value ) output=key;
      // return output. As long as it is null, it will continue to with next entry.
      return output;
    });
    return output; // returns the key
}

var entryToDelete = "1234"
var key = getKeyFromValue(jsondata, entryToDelete);
console.log('key', key);
// if the key is set (no need to test for not null)
if (key) delete jsondata[key];
console.log(jsondata);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need!

```
var entryToDelete = 1234
for (var key in jsondata) {
    if (jsondata.hasOwnProperty(key) && jsondata[key].entry == entryToDelete) {
        delete jsondata[key];
    }
}
```